# problems configuring etcd2 for TLS

Tags: coreos, etcd

I have at home two CoreOS stable v1122.2.0 machines. both of them are registered at discovery.etcd.io properly. (i see both of them registered at https://ip:2380 when i browse to the discovery url).

the first server is 10.79.218.2, and the 2nd is 10.79.218.3.

I'm trying to configure etcd for tls. so I created the required certificates and I configured etcd2 for tls. all the configuration (of the first server with local ip of 10.79.218.2) is in the cloud-config.yml file:

```
 #cloud-config

 write_files:
  - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "etcd:etcd"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/server1.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "etcd:etcd"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/server1-key.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "etcd:etcd"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d/10-calico.conf"
    content: |
      {
          "name": "calico",
          "type": "flannel",
          "delegate": {
              "type": "calico",
              "etcd_endpoints": "https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379",
              "log_level": "none",
              "log_level_stderr": "info",
              "hostname": "10.79.218.2",
              "policy": {
                  "type": "k8s",
                  "k8s_api_root": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/"
              }
          }
      }
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/policy-controller.yaml"
    content: |
     apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: calico-policy-controller
        namespace: calico-system
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
          # The Calico policy controller.
          - name: k8s-policy-controller
            image: calico/kube-policy-controller:v0.2.0
            env:
              - name: ETCD_ENDPOINTS
                value: "https://10.79.218.2:2379,http://10.79.218.3:2379"
              - name: K8S_API
                value: "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
              - name: LEADER_ELECTION
                value: "true"
          # Leader election container used by the policy controller.
          - name: leader-elector
            image: quay.io/calico/leader-elector:v0.1.0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            args:
              - "--election=calico-policy-election"
              - "--election-namespace=calico-system"
              - "--http=127.0.0.1:4040"

  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
    content: |
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: kube-scheduler
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - name: kube-scheduler
          image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.3.6_coreos.0
          command:
          - /hyperkube
          - scheduler
          - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
          - --leader-elect=true
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              host: 127.0.0.1
              path: /healthz
              port: 10251
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 1
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
    content: |
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: kube-controller-manager
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - name: kube-controller-manager
          image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.3.6_coreos.0
          command:
          - /hyperkube
          - controller-manager
          - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
          - --leader-elect=true
          - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
          - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              host: 127.0.0.1
              path: /healthz
              port: 10252
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
            name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
            readOnly: true
          - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
            name: ssl-certs-host
            readOnly: true
        volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
          name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
        - hostPath:
            path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
          name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml"
    content: |
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: kube-proxy
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - name: kube-proxy
          image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.3.6_coreos.0
          command:
          - /hyperkube
          - proxy
          - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
          - --proxy-mode=iptables
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
            name: ssl-certs-host
            readOnly: true
        volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
          name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
    content: |
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: kube-apiserver
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - name: kube-apiserver
          image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.3.6_coreos.0
          command:
          - /hyperkube
          - apiserver
          - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
          - --etcd-servers=https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379
          - --allow-privileged=true
          - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/24
          - --secure-port=443
          - --advertise-address=10.79.218.2
          - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota
          - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
          - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
          - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
          - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
          - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1=true,extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true
          ports:
          - containerPort: 443
            hostPort: 443
            name: https
          - containerPort: 8080
            hostPort: 8080
            name: local
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
            name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
            readOnly: true
          - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
            name: ssl-certs-host
            readOnly: true
        volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
          name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
        - hostPath:
            path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
          name: ssl-certs-host
  - path: "/etc/flannel/options.env"
    content: |
     FLANNELD_IFACE=10.79.218.2
     FLANNELD_ETCD_ENDPOINTS=https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "root:root"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "root:root"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem"
    permissions: "0600"
    owner: "root:root"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 ssh_authorized_keys:
          - "ssh-rsa ... ufk@ufk-osx-music"
 coreos:
   update:
     reboot-strategy: etcd-lock
   etcd2:
     discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/...
    # multi-region and multi-cloud deployments need to use $public_ipv4
     advertise-client-urls: https://10.79.218.2:2379
     initial-advertise-peer-urls: https://10.79.218.2:2380
     # listen on both the official ports and the legacy ports
     # legacy ports can be omitted if your application doesn't depend on them
     listen-client-urls: https://0.0.0.0:2379
     listen-peer-urls: https://10.79.218.2:2380
   units:
     - name: 00-enp4s0.network
       runtime: true
       content: |
        [Match]
        Name=enp4s0

        [Network]
        Address=10.79.218.2/24
        Gateway=10.79.218.232
        DNS=8.8.8.8
     - name: var-lib-rkt.mount
       enable: true
       command: start
       content: |
         [Mount]
         What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/23cc3284-e121-4448-b755-b74b5a022251
         Where=/var/lib/rkt
         Type=btrfs
         Options=loop,discard
     - name: etcd2.service
       command: start
       drop-ins:
        - name: 30-certs.conf
          content: |
           [Service]
           Environment="ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/server1.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/server1-key.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true"
           Environment="ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/server1.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/server1-key.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
           Environment="ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true"
     - name: flanneld.service
       command: start
       drop-ins:
        - name: 50-network-config.conf
          content: |
           [Service]
           ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{"Network":"10.1.0.0/16", "Backend": {"Type": "vxlan"}}'
        - name: 40-ExecStartPre-symlink.conf
          content: |
           [Service]
           ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ln -sf /etc/flannel/options.env /run/flannel/options.env
     - name: kubelet.service
       enable: false
       content: |
        [Service]
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests

        Environment=KUBELET_VERSION=v1.3.6_coreos.0
        ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
           --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 \
           --network-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d \
           --network-plugin=cni \
           --register-schedulable=false \
           --allow-privileged=true \
           --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
           --hostname-override=10.79.218.2 \
           --cluster-dns=8.8.8.8 \
           --cluster-domain=cluster.local
        Restart=always
        RestartSec=10
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
     - name: calico-node.service
       enable: false
       content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Calico per-host agent
        Requires=network-online.target
        After=network-online.target

        [Service]
        Slice=machine.slice
        Environment=CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING=true
        Environment=HOSTNAME=10.79.218.2
        Environment=IP=${ADVERTISE_IP}
        Environment=FELIX_FELIXHOSTNAME=10.79.218.2
        Environment=CALICO_NETWORKING=false
        Environment=NO_DEFAULT_POOLS=true
        Environment=ETCD_ENDPOINTS=https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt run --inherit-env --stage1-from-dir=stage1-fly.aci \
        --volume=modules,kind=host,source=/lib/modules,readOnly=false \
        --mount=volume=modules,target=/lib/modules \
        --trust-keys-from-https quay.io/calico/node:v0.19.0

        KillMode=mixed
        Restart=always
        TimeoutStartSec=0

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- i removed important stuff (like keys) and replaced them with `...`
- i have kubelet and calico configured but disabled for now till i'll get etcd2 up and running with tls.

so I'm trying to run `etcdctl` from my mac pro laptop to list the etcd2 members (while being connected to the same local network) using the command

```
./etcdctl --endpoints="https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379" --key-file="./cfssl/client-key.pem" --cert-file="./cfssl/client.pem" --ca-file="./cfssl/ca.pem"  member list
```

and I get in response

```
Try '--no-sync' if you want to access non-published client endpoints(https://10.79.218.2:2379,https://10.79.218.3:2379).
Error:  client: no endpoints available
```

running the same command with `--no-sync` results the following:

```
Failed to get leader:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
```

I created the certificates as described in https://github.com/coreos/docs/blob/master/os/generate-self-signed-certificates.md

what am I missing ?

thanks

## update

so i found out about https://github.com/coreos/etcd/tree/master/hack/tls-setup. and I re-created the certificates using this script, and I configured my coreos etcd2 servers with these scripts.

it created the following certificates:
ca-key.pem
ca.csr
ca.pem
etcd1-key.pem
etcd1.csr
etcd1.pem
etcd2-key.pem
etcd2.csr
etcd2.pem
etcd3-key.pem
etcd3.csr
etcd3.pem
proxy1-key.pem
proxy1.csr
proxy1.pem

the problem is that I don't see any client certificate.. so  I don't quite understand what certificates to pass as parameters for etcdctl to work from my desktop. any ideas ?

## update 2

so i found how to use etcdctl with tls.. i think. but still I get errors.
I executed the following command:

```
/etcdctl --endpoint=https://10.79.218.2:2379 --ca-file=./certs/ca.pem --cert-file=./certs/etcd1.pem --key-file=./certs/etcd1-key.pem --no-sync ls
```

but I get the error

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.79.218.2 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it work. i didn't read the instructions of hack/tls-setup correctly. I thought I needed to download req-csr.json to the hack/tls-setup directory while I actually just needed to edit hack/tls-setup/config/req-csr.json file before issuing `make` command. after doing that sometimes I got timeout errors, so I just ran `etcdctl` with timeout of 10 seconds.

the full command that I needed to run is

```
etcdctl --endpoint=https://10.79.218.2:2379 --ca-file=./certs/ca.pem --cert-file=./certs/etcd1.pem --key-file=./certs/etcd1-key.pem  --timeout=10s member list
```